# How to step through playbook in ansible-tower or awx (like ansible-playbook --step)?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

Is it possible to perform step through when using ansible-tower or awx? If yes, how?

```
--step                one-step-at-a-time: confirm each task before running
```

Comment: This is an interactive option to ansible-playbook. AWX/Tower does not run the playbook interactively. The answer is: no.